# Import certain part of textfile to matlab

Tags: matlab, file, file-io, io

I am new to Matlab and I have a text file like the one below.

I want to ignore the first 7 rows with writings and import the rest in matrix form. Thanks for help.

```
5.7.2014 20:01:30

C:\Users\s\Desktop

C:\Users\s\Desktop

Activation

0,1

20,20,0 255,255,0   137,137,0

0

0   0,104797

0   0,104798

0   0,104799

0   0,104798

..........
```

Comment: Do you want each element from a row to occupy a position in the matrix, or each row to occupy a position? For instance would 0 and 1 from row 1 would occupy positions (1,1) and (1,2)? I'm asking because you might want to use a cell array instead of a matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITING THE ANSWER AFTER THE OP SPECIFIED MORE EXACTLY WHAT HE WANTS :)**

The first 13 lines can be skipped using the option `HeaderLines` when calling `textscan`, in accordance with the [official documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#inputarg_HeaderLines).

Assuming the file is the one provided by the OP then, calling it `test.txt`, the following code will do.

```
% read the text file original text file
orig = fileread('test.txt');

% replace commas with dots
newfile = strrep(orig,',','.');

% create a new text file in write mode
fid_w = fopen('test_mod.txt','w')

% write this modified version of the file to disk
fprintf(fid_w,'%s',newfile);

% close this text file
fclose(fid_w)

% open the modified text file in read mode
fid_r = fopen('test_mod.txt','r');

% put the data in a cell array, assuming strings and skipping the
% first 13 lines
indata = textscan(fid_r, '%s', 'HeaderLines',13, 'Delimiter', '\r');

% close the modified text file
fclose(fid_r);

% cell --> char
indata = cell2mat(indata{1});

% char --> number
indata = str2num(indata)
```

This should be the sought output:

```
indata =

         0    0.1048
         0    0.1048
         0    0.1048
         0    0.1048
```

I am posting the output of a `whos indata` as well:

```
  Name        Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  indata      4x2                64  double
```

Oh, and of course `indata` contains the whole `0.104797` number, it is just rounded to 4 decimals. If you wish to see the full output just issue a `format long`. More info about `format` in the [official docs](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/format.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what I need is actuaally a 4x2 matrix and I wanted to skip the first 3 rows of your indata result as well I might not be very clear on explaining that.

Comment: Thank you for better explaining your needs. I edited my answer, now it should be fit for purpose!

Comment: One last thing I want to ask you some of the data I have dont have an empty line between two rows like my example. When I apply this code indata results as two numbers combined and output gives error. Can you help with this also. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try this:

```
clear
clc

fileID = fopen('TestFile.rtf'); % I copied you file in a dummy document. 

txt = fscanf(fileID,'%c');
Data = textscan(txt,'%[^\n]','delimiter','\n'); % look for line changes (sorry I don't remember the real name for this)

YourData = cell(7,1);

for p = 12:18 % specific for your document. You can make it more general of course

k = p-11;
YourData{k} = Data{1}{p};

YourData{k} = regexprep(YourData{k},'\\',''); % remove the \ if there are any

end

disp(YourData)
```

which gives this:

```
    '0,1'
    '20,20,0 255,255,0 137,137,0'
    '0'
    '0 0,104797'
    '0 0,104798'
    '0 0,104799'
    '0 0,104798'
```

where every row contains a string. You can then play around with the result to build your matrix/cell array as you like. Hope that helps!